# specific split with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex, it's an exemple:

```
/par(tir|te|s)|(quitter.*maison)|((heure|quand).*(rendez-vous|journée))/i
```

I would like to split it by "|" in a regular expression but this character can't be inside parenthesis for the explode. So the expected result have to be that:

```
1: par(tir|te|s)
2: (quitter.*maison)
3: ((heure|quand).*(rendez-vous|journée))
```

My mind is in trouble, someone can help me?

Comment: Please update the question with input and expected output.

Comment: It's done yet, the regex in example is input and the second quote is expected output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a huge help from [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703187/count-parentheses-with-regular-expression), I was able to construct [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/5SVXuc/1).
It matches parenthesis with their content, including preceding text:

```
(?:\w+)?\((?:[^()]*|\((?:[^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)
```

However I must say that nested parenthesis are super hard to handle with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on this regex, which achieves precisely the output you specified from the input sample provided:

```
/\|(?!(?:\w+\|?)+\))/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex `/\|(?![^\(]*\))/g`

```js
const str = '/par(tir|te|s)|(quitter.maison)|((heure|quand).(rendez-vous|journée))/i';
console.log(str.split(/\|(?![^\(]*\))/g));
```