# How to use regular expression to remove all math expression in latex file

Tags: python, regex, latex

Suppose I have a string which consists of a part of latex file. How can I use python re module to remove any math expression in it?

e.g:

```
text="This is an example $$a \text{$a$}$$. How to remove it? Another random math expression $\mathbb{R}$..."
```

I would like my function to return `ans="This is an example . How to remove it?  Another random math expression ..."`.

Thank you!

Comment: For those readers of your question who do not know LaTex markup syntax, you should provide what the rules are for knowing what should and should not be removed from your text.

Comment: Your question can be broken down in two separate questions:  1. How to recognize math expressions in latex files (what is their pattern). 2. How to use the 're' module to remove a substring from a string.  Do you have the answer to the first part? Can you let us know, or is it an actual part of your question?

Comment: Let me put it this way: is there a string such that re.compile(r'that string') will give me all location of math expression when I run re.finditer ?

Comment: @Ben You are not answering our questions, and therefore we may not be able to help you.

Comment: Whenever I see an expression $something inside$ or $$ something inside$$, they are math expression.

Comment: @Ben For the given example, you can use the regex [`(\$+)(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*\1`](https://regex101.com/r/3vGNhE/1). Here is the [code](https://regex101.com/r/3vGNhE/1/codegen?language=python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(\$+)(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*\1
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vGNhE/1)**

[**Code**](https://regex101.com/r/3vGNhE/1/codegen?language=python)

**Explanation:**

- `(\$+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of `$` and captures it in Group 1
- `(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that does not start with what was captured in Group 1
- `\1` - matches the contents of Group 1 again

Replace each match with a blank string.

As suggested by @torek, we should not match 3 or more consecutive `$`, hence changing the expression to [`(\${1,2})(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*\1`](https://regex101.com/r/3vGNhE/2)

Comment: For this particular case, replace the above with `\${1,2}` since we don't want to match `$$$` as a single symbol.

Comment: I think this expression is good enough for my each purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly said that *regular expressions cannot count*, which is kind of a loose way of describing a problem more formally discussed in [Count parentheses with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18703187/1256452).  See that for what this means.

Now, with that in mind, note that LaTeX math expressions *can* include nested sub-equations, which can include further nested sub-equations, and so on.  This is analogous to the problem of detecting whether a closing parenthesis closes an inner parenthesized expression (as in (for instance) this example, where the first one does not) or an outer parenthesis.  Therefore, regular expressions are not going to be powerful enough to handle the full general case.

If you're willing to do a less-than-complete job, you *can* construct a regular expression that finds `$...$` and `$$...$$`.  You will need to pay attention to the particular regular expression language available.  Python's is essentially the same as Perl's here.

Importantly, these `$`-matchers will completely miss `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, `\begin{eqnarray} ... \end{eqnarray}`, and so on.  We've already noted that handling LaTeX expression parsing with a mere regular expression recognizer is inadequate, so if you want to do a good job—while ignoring the complexity of lower-level TeX manipulation of token types, where one can change any individual character's [category code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode) —you will want a more general parser.  You can then tokenize `\begin`, `{`, `}`, and words, and match up the begin/end pairs.  You can also tokenize `$` and `$$` and match those up.  Since parsers *can* count, in exactly the way that regular expressions can't, you can do a much better job this way.

Answer (score 0):

The Regular Expression

```
( |\n)(\${1,2})([^$]|\n|\\\$)+\2
```

finds all inline and displayed formulas of type `$...$` and `$$...$$`.

Use the Regular Expression

```
\\begin\{align\}((.|\n)(?!\\end\{align\}))*(.|\n)\\end\{align\}
```

to find aligned formulas of type `\begin{align}...\end{align}` (compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/remove-everything-that-is-in-math-mode).

These Regular Expressions work well in the `Kate` editor for the following `LaTeX` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This \LaTeX\ code is riddled with dollars \$'s
and double-dollars \$\$'s. The prices for $%
A$ and $B$ are inline $A=10\,\$,%
B=20\,\$\$$, displayed $$A=10\,\$,%
\quad B=20\,\$\$,$$%
and aligned 
\begin{align}
A& =10\,\$,  \label{$} \\
B& =20\,\$\$.  \label{$$}
\end{align}%
From (\ref{$}) and (\ref{$$}), we know the
prices for $A$ and
$B$.

Here is a further display $$A+A=2A,%
\quad B\times B=B^{2},$$%
and a further alignment 
\begin{align}
A+A& =2A,  \label{$$$} \\
B\times B& =B^{2}.  \label{$$$$}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The math free result is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This \LaTeX\ code is riddled with dollars \$'s
and double-dollars \$\$'s. The prices for  and  are inline , displayed %
and aligned 
 %
From (\ref{$}) and (\ref{$$}), we know the
prices for  and .

Here is a further display %
and a further alignment 


\end{document}
```